# get users search not working with array

Tags: php, array

Here's my code:

```
function prefix_get_users(){
   $args=array(
      'blog_id' => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
      'search'  => 'mark'
   );
   $all_users=get_users($args);
   $arr=array();
   foreach ($all_users as $val) {
      $arr[]=$val->data->user_login;
   }
   $resp = array (
       'success'    => true,
       'data'       => json_encode($arr)
   );
   wp_send_json($resp);

 }
```

The code is working by getting all the user successfully but when to try to use search it's not working and give me empty array by ajax (data[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_users` looks for an exact match for the value in `search` in the email *address*, *URL*, *ID*, *username* or *display_name* fields... it doesn't look in the *first name* field.

As you can't search the first name directly, you could instead look for people with a username or display name that *starts with* it by using the wildcard `*` in the search string, e.g.:

```
$args=array(
   'blog_id' => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
   'search'  => 'mark*'   /* Note the * wildcard to match anything starting with "mark" */
);
$all_users=get_users($args);
[...]
```